# Android: Is there a way to generate an ".aab" file of my app without signature?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-app-bundle

I tried the traditional generation of app bundle (.aab) without signature like we do for '.apk' using android studio menu option : ***Build >> Build bundle(s)/Apk(s) >> Build bundle(s)***.

Normally, it should generate an '.aab' file and the name of the file should contains the prefix 'unsigned' like in the '.apk' file generated in same way but it doesn't exists.

When I deliver this .aab file to my client, he say to me that the file is signed.

My Gradle file :

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion compile_sdk_version
    buildToolsVersion build_tools_version

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.**"

        minSdkVersion min_sdk_version
        targetSdkVersion compile_sdk_version

        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        renderscriptTargetApi min_sdk_version
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }

    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes true
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {

        production {
            dimension 'default'
            versionCode rootProject.ext.version_code_production
            versionName rootProject.ext.version_name_production
        }

        stagging {
            dimension 'default'
            versionCode rootProject.ext.version_code_stagging
            versionName rootProject.ext.version_name_stagging
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        debug {       
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }

        qualif {    
            applicationIdSuffix ".re7"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {

        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true

        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 11
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
  ..
}
}
```

How should I generate one without signature  ?

**Note:** in gradle, I eleminate every signature declaration.

Comment: What does your gradle build files look like?

Comment: You may have to use Gradle or `bundletool` directly: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#build_bundle

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried but it forces a default signature for some reason, so I don't know if it is signed or not.

Comment: @DevWithZachary I included the gradle file !

Comment: I think when you create a .aab or .apk file it will always be signed with some key.  If you do not specify the signing key it will use .debug key to sign apk or .aab fil.  Unsigned files should be rejected by device AFAK.

Comment: Unsigned files are not signed with any keys. That's why they are called unsigned

Answer (score -1):

`gradlew bundleRelease`

Make sure that `signingConfig` in `release` build type is commented out